# Why tasks scheduled to one node of my Mesos cluster constantly get LOST?

Tags: cluster-computing, mesos

I have a small Mesos cluster of 5 nodes that I manage myself. (without Marathon etc.)

My usage is simple, schedule parallelized tasks to nodes. While tasks schedule to one of the node always get "LOST" state.

There's nothing special with the configuration / node, they have same hardware and softwares are installed with the same script.

Does anyone know what could go wrong, and what shall I look at to figure out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

can you check in two places (and potentially post relevant here):
 - Mesos slave/master log
 - the Tasks stout/sterr output (which is reachable via the sandbox link in the Mesos UI)

Thanks!